# Making “Reformat code” on request block - it has other layout I need

Tags: php, phpstorm, code-formatting

Laravel 9 app in PhpStorm 2021.1.4

When I make “Reformat code” on a block of code I got :

```php
$totalVotesCount = Vote::getByName($filterName, true)
                       ->getByStatus($filterStatus)
                       ->getByIsQuiz($filterIsQuiz)
                       ->getByIsHomepage($filterIsHomepage)
                       ->with('voteCategory')
                       ->with('creator')
                       ->getByVoteCategoryId($filterVoteCategoryId)
                       ->count();
```

But I need to have these lines formatted like this:

```php
$totalVotesCount = Vote::getByName($filterName, true)
    ->getByStatus($filterStatus)
    ->getByIsQuiz($filterIsQuiz)
    ->getByIsHomepage($filterIsHomepage)
    ->with('voteCategory')
    ->with('creator')
    ->getByVoteCategoryId($filterVoteCategoryId)
    ->count();
```

Where can I configure these options?

Comment: The way to find out the needed option for you is to know what you **already have there** right now: 1) export your current Code Style in XML format; 2) share it as a file (Google Drive/Dropbox or alike) so it can be downloaded; 3) Me (or another person who wants to answer) will import it on another machine and check for applicable options. The code style I have in my IDE test project formats it differently...

Comment: Right now it looks like you need to look at your options in `Code Style | PHP | Wrapping and Braces | Chained method calls`, possibly disable `Align when multiline`.